# AttributeError: 'TreeQuerySet' object has no attribute 'get_family'

Tags: python, django, django-mptt

I am using django mptt and i want to get all whole family of one child. 
When i call other functions it works fine

For example i filter object and call function get_family

```
p = Platform.objects.filter(name__startswith='signals')
s = p.get_family()
print(s)
```

but getting error

> AttributeError: 'TreeQuerySet' object has no attribute 'get_family'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get_family` is a method on the model. But as the error shows, `filter` returns a QuerySet - ie a collection of models. You need to choose one to call your method on.

Either use the `.first()` method:

```
p = Platform.objects.filter(name__startswith='signals').first()
```

or, if you're sure there is only ever one Platform object that matches, use `get` instead of filter:

```
p = Platform.objects.get(name__startswith='signals')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error says that you are either trying to access `get_family` on the wrong thing, or that you have not implemented the library correctly.
Just having a glance at http://django-mptt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/models.html?highlight=get_family#get-family, you can see that you need to extend `MPTTModel` to have that function available

Comment: Have you created / run migrations? I can't provide much help as I am not familiar with the library, but  `isinstance(Platform.objects.first(), MPTTModel)` should be True